# How does order parameter work in cucumber's hooks (After, Before)?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

When I use order parameter while using hooks, they were not executing based on order parameter's value. They were being executing in the order they were declared.

Code Snippets with order parameter:

```java
package com.google.test.support;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class CucumberHooks {

    @Before(order = 2)
    public void setup_url() {
        System.out.println("check before hooks");
    }

    @Before(order = 1)
    public void setup_browser() {
        System.out.println("test before hooks");
    }

    @After(order = 1)
    public void tearDown_close() {
        System.out.println("test after hooks");
    }

    @After(order = 2)
    public void tearDown_logout() {
        System.out.println("check after hooks");
    }

}
```

Code snippet without order parameter:

```java
package com.google.test.support;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class CucumberHooks {

    @Before
    public void setup_url() {
        System.out.println("check before hooks");
    }

    @Before
    public void setup_browser() {
        System.out.println("test before hooks");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown_close() {
        System.out.println("test after hooks");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown_logout() {
        System.out.println("check after hooks");
    }

}
```

Output while executing the both codes:

```
check before hooks
test before hooks
test after hooks
check after hooks
```

My understanding, as per official documentation, is that order parameter in @Before will execute in ascending order while in @After in descending order

Can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: You could confirm this yourself by changing the order in your annotations and see its effects.

Comment: Yeah, I have changed the order, but it is executing sequential flow. Order does not have any impact on it.

Comment: So could you state your question again?

Answer (score 0):

If you check test [HookOrderTest](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/core/src/test/java/io/cucumber/core/runner/HookOrderTest.java) directly in [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) project. You can see that as it's in documentation `@Before` will be executed in ascending order while `@After` will be executed in descending order.

In case you do mix and for some hooks you specify order and for some not, it works like this. If you use `@Before` without specified order, hook is executed as last. In case you use `@After`, hook is executed as first one.